# Creating an Object array from another class

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

Okay this should be simple. But I have been at this for a good hour and cannot figure out why its a nullpointerexception.

I need to create an array for "Sally" and then test its length, which should be 0. This is in the main method of the driver class.

```
 LendingItem[] sallysItemList = sally.getSignedOutItems();
if (sallysItemList.length == 0)
```

and this is in the object class that created sally. that rotten B.

```
    private LendingItem[] signedOutItems;

public LendingItem[] getSignedOutItems() {
    return signedOutItems;
}
```

I feel like I need to maybe declare the Lending item as

```
private LendingItem[] signedOutItems = {};
```

but I still get errors with that also.

EDIT:

Im going to add more so that its more understandable what I need to make happen

Provided code below.

```
   System.out.println("\n*** Test case #1: Create a CardHolder object & test accessors");
CardHolder sally = new CardHolder("Sally Smith",
                                  152,
                                  "454-1234");
System.out.println("Name:     " + sally.getName()
               + "\nAppt #:   " + sally.getAptNumber()
               + "\nPhone:    " + sally.getPhoneNumber()
               + "\nMember #: " + sally.getMembershipNumber());

LendingItem[] sallysItemList = sally.getSignedOutItems();
if (sallysItemList.length == 0)
  System.out.println("Correct result: Sally has zero lending items.");
else
  System.out.println(">> ERROR: Sally has more than zero lending items.");


 System.out.println("\n*** Test case #6: Sign out one LendingItem");

if(sally.signOut(testItemList[0]))
{ System.out.println("Correct result: Sally signed out an item successfully.");
  sallysItemList = sally.getSignedOutItems();
  if (sallysItemList.length == 1)
    System.out.println("Correct result: Sally has one lending item.");
  else
    System.out.println(">> ERROR: Sally has other than one lending item.");
}
else
  System.out.println(">> ERROR: Sally was unable to sign out an item.");
```

This is my code thus far.
Just need to return the current signed out items.

```
    public LendingItem[] getSignedOutItems() {
    return signedOutItems;
}
```

This is how we are expected to add to our array, it needs to return a boolean

```
    public boolean signOut(LendingItem lendingItem) {
    if (signedOutItems.length < 7) {
        signedOutItems[0] = lendingItem;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Dont need the outright code just an idea of how to actually accomplish this.

Comment: `private signedOutItems = new LendingItem[0];` Tada!

Comment: will this allow me to add more than one thing to the array though?

Comment: no. An array of length 0 is immutable and nothing can be added.

Comment: If you want to add elements in the future, use an `ArrayList`

Comment: Okay. this make another error for me because I need to test to see how many spots in the array are filled and return the contents...

Comment: For the assignment the teacher provides the driver class and we need to create the Object classes. Its good practice for team coding but I the instructions are super vague so I have to figure out everything as I go.

Comment: There are no contents in a zero-lengthed array. A well structured for or for-each loop will never iterate.

Comment: Are you sure it's _supposed_ to have length 0?

Comment: Also I would use arrayList but we havent learned that yet and ar't allowed to use it in the assignment or we will lose marks.

Comment: if (sallysItemList.length == 0) - this is part of the driver class provided, we arnt allowed to change this either. So we need to figure out how to have an array that holds up to 7 things, but can have a length of zero if nothing is added to it yet? like i said super vague instructions.

Comment: That's impossible, sorry.

Comment: right? - I dont know what he is expecting use to write for code on that. I think Im just going to take the driver class, and turn that part into the array list.

Comment: After making my answer, I saw the end of your code. That signOut method makes no sense. the `length` is never going to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to make a crazy class which uses an array to maintain the list, with the ability to return arrays with different sizes.

```
public class CardHolder {
    private LendingItem[] lendingItems;

    public CardHolder () {
        lendingItems = new LendingItem[0];
    }

    public boolean signOut(LendingItem item) {
        if (lendingItems.length >= 7) return false;
        lendingItems = Arrays.copyOf(lendingItems, lendingItems.length + 1); //copies old array, but adding a null value to the new one
        lendingItems[lendingItems.length - 1] = item; //replace the null value with the new item to add
        return true;
    }

    public LendingItem[] getSignedOutItems() {
        return lendingItems;
    }
}
```

That should help get you started..

Comment: THANK YOU. this helps a bunch. basically it was like "this is how you make arrays, now do this assignment."

Comment: @NIcholasTremblay you're welcome, but it doesn't look like this is what your teacher wants either... Either way, I edited the code to be closer to what he might want.

Comment: This works, its returns the true statement and I completely understand this. For all intensive purpose this completely works without using array lists. you @yts are a gentleman and a scholar

Answer (score 2):

This

```
private LendingItem[] signedOutItems;
```

is equivalent to

```
private LendingItem[] signedOutItems = null;
```

so when you do,

```
public LendingItem[] getSignedOutItems() {
    return signedOutItems;
}
```

It returns `null`. Initialize and add elements to your array. Something like,

```
private LendingItem[] signedOutItems = new LendingItem[10];
```

creates an array with space for 10 `LendingItem`(s). Note that each of those 10 slots is initialized to `null`.

Comment: As a side-note, arrays are awkward, especially as fields. Lists are a lot more convenient.

Comment: @maksimov Or realistically, most instances of `Collection`